# Sending param to bash from cmd

Tags: bash, cmd.exe, alias

I want to be able to invoke the `file` command from within `cmd`.

This works, but is a pain to type:

```
bash -c "file filename.ext"
```

This is much easier, and works as expected...

```
DOSKEY file=bash -c "file $*"
file filename.ext
```

... except when a filename contains a space:

```
C:\> file "the filename.ext"
the: cannot open `the' (No such file or directory)
```

Single quotes don't help:

```
DOSKEY file=bash -c "file '$*'"
file "the filename.ext"
```

Result:

```
filename.ext': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
filename.ext': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Nor do quotes escaped with quotes:

```
DOSKEY file=bash -c "file ""$*"""
file "the filename.ext"
```

```
the:          cannot open `the' (No such file or directory)
filename.ext: cannot open `filename.ext' (No such file or directory)
```

Or backslashes:

```
DOSKEY file=bash -c "file \"$*\""
file "the filename.ext"
```

```
filename.ext": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
filename.ext": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DOSKEY file=bash -c "file '$*'"
```

**Usage examples:**

"Usual" filename:

```
file NoExtensionJpg
```

> ```
> NoExtensionJpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=11, manufacturer=Apple, model=iPhone 6s, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=162, yresolution=170, resolutionunit=2, software=11.4, atetime=2019:06:01 11:20:54, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 4032x3024, components 3
> ```

Filename contains a space:

```
file export - Copy.txt
```

> ```
> export - Copy.txt: Windows Registry little-endian text (Win2K or above)
> ```

Filename contains a `cmd`-poisonous character:

```
file NUL&pause&exit
```

> ```
> NUL&pause&exit: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
> ```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I already tried this syntax as posted in my original question

Comment: @user1215114 but you use double-quoted filename `file "the filename.ext"` and that's why you get those `unexpected EOF` and `unexpected end of file` errors. Just try `file the filename.ext` **without** double quotes.

Comment: Kinda hard to do when the shell automatically adds the quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cygwin or MSYS then there's already `file.exe` that you can call directly from cmd. Some terminals like MobaXterm or git bash also use MSYS or cygwin under the hood so you don't actually need to call from bash

If you're using WSL then you need to transform the Windows path to the WSL path because the Linux subsystem doesn't understand Windows paths

```
DOSKEY file=bash -c 'file^ ^"$(wslpath^ ^"$*^")^"'
```

But using a batch file will be much simpler. Just save the below line to a file and place it somewhere in PATH

```
@bash -c "file \"$(wslpath \"%~1\")\""
```

If you're using Cygwin/MSYS but you really want to call from bash then you must do the same using [`cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) instead of [`wslpath`](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2017/12/19/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17063-pc/)

Comment: While this does work for non-spaced filenames, both approaches produce "wslpath: Invalid argument" when called with a quoted filename

Comment: @user1215114 I already knew that. Use `%~1` like in my second command but that way you can only pass one file at a time. Of you'll have to loop through all parameters and use `%~N` to remove double quotes. Anyway just use powershell and avoid these nasty cmd things